Understand verse Isaiah 29:12
I am currently in the process of understanding various religions and studying them.
While studying the Quran's English translation, I came across this footnote about this verse

96:5 عَلَّمَ ٱلْإِنسَـٰنَ مَا لَمْ يَعْلَمْ ٥
taught humanity what they knew not.[1]  — Dr. Mustafa Khattab, The
Clear Quran
[1] Verses 1-5 are known to be the first ever revealed of the Quran.
The Prophet (ﷺ) was retreating at a cave in the outskirts of Mecca
when the angel Gabriel appeared to him, squeezing him tightly and
ordering him to read. Since the Prophet (ﷺ) was unlettered, he
responded, “I cannot read.” Ultimately, Gabriel taught him: “Read in
the Name of your Lord …” Some scholars believe that this encounter is
the fulfilment of Isaiah 29:12, which states, “Then the book will be
given to the one who is illiterate, saying, ‘Read this.’ And he will
say, ‘I cannot read.’”

Here's [the link][1] to this footnote.
I explored Isaiah 29:12 but couldn't understand it much because maybe I could not get the right/clear translation for this verse. Please help me understand Isaiah 29:12. Does it really mean that a holy book will be given by God to someone illiterate in the future?
Sorry for any mistakes as this is my first question on this forum! Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://quran.com/96/5

https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask for a pure translation of scripture. This site is generally for questions about Christian beliefs, but this question doesn't seem to be about how the verse relates to Christianity

There isn't really any doubt about the translation of this verse, it's more or less as written in the question. It doesn't make sense on its own because it's part of a larger block, you need to read it in the context of the chapter (which I believe makes it clear that claiming this as a prophecy of Muhammad is wishful thinking).

You need to find other platforms like facebook and search youtube for these topics, bec this site moderators does not allow any posts which go against Islamic profession, and deemed as offensive. They are also better platforms for such debates and ques. Answering-islam is a good site to begin this search for christian responses.

Thanks all for your response!

11 And the vision of all this has become to you like the words of a book that is sealed. When men give it to one who can read, saying, “Read this,” he says, “I cannot, for it is sealed.” 12 And when they give the book to one who cannot read, saying, “Read this,” he says, “I cannot read.” (Isaiah 29:11-12; ESV)
In order to understand this verse, we need to look at the context of Isaiah 29. It speaks about prophets and seers of the city of Ariel being "drunk but not with wine" and being possessed by a "spirit of deep sleep". The passage tries to say that those who were generally able to understand God's word (prophets), were too spiritually drunk to do so. They (prophets) also couldn't get any help from the common people who were not skilled in such matters.
